# How to cast a snapshot value into a dictionary value with typescript?

Tags: swift, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I convert a snapshot value into a dictionary value of type `[String: AnyObject]`

I am trying to accomplish the bellow line in swift but in **Typescript**, so that I can loop through the keys. How can I do that? How do I cast a snapshot returned by firebase query in typescript into a dictionary of `[string: AnyObject]`

```
let snapValue = snap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
```

TypeScript query:

```
const userRef = admin.database().ref('PeopleWhoFollowMe').child(uid)
const fetchAndUpdate = userRef.once('value')
.then(snap => {
```

Comment: What is the type of a `snap.value`?

Comment: This doesn't look like TypeScript, and swift doesn't run in Cloud Functions, so I'm removing the unrelated tags.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am trying to convert this line of swift to typescript. Or generally know how to "do" that line in typescript.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin dataSnapshot I believe its what is returned by firebase query

Comment: Can you show how you are querying the data in TypeScript.

Comment: check update @ShaunLuttin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `snap` in your query is a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot) type object.  Click through that link to read the API documentation for it.

You can get the raw JavaScript data object of a DataSnapshot using its [val()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#val) method.  Then you can iterate its properties using any normal JavaScript technique that's discussed heavily already on Stack Overflow: [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own converter as described in [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter).

`firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter<T>` - Converter used by `withConverter()` to transform user objects of type T into Firestore data.

Using the converter allows you to specify generic type arguments when storing and retrieving objects from Firestore.

```
class Post {
  constructor(readonly title: string, readonly author: string) {}

  toString(): string {
    return this.title + ', by ' + this.author;
  }
}

const postConverter = {
  toFirestore(post: Post): firebase.firestore.DocumentData {
    return {title: post.title, author: post.author};
  },
  fromFirestore(
    snapshot: firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot,
    options: firebase.firestore.SnapshotOptions
  ): Post {
    const data = snapshot.data(options)!;
    return new Post(data.title, data.author);
  }
};

const postSnap = await firebase.firestore()
  .collection('posts')
  .withConverter(postConverter)
  .doc().get();
const post = postSnap.data();
if (post !== undefined) {
  post.title; // string
  post.toString(); // Should be defined
  post.someNonExistentProperty; // TS error
}
```